# Numpy out of memory

Tags: python, memory, numpy

I have two variables, x and y.  x is

`type(x) = <class 'numpy.matrixlib.defmatrix.matrix'>`

`type(y) = <type 'numpy.ndarray'>`

`x.shape = (869250, 1)`

`y.shape = (869250,)`

x+y gives a MemoryError, despite the fact that I have around 5 gb free.  This seems rather odd - does anyone have an idea as to what might be going on?

This is numpy 1.5.1, python 2.7, on 64 bit Linux.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Are you sure you're doing what you want to be doing?

```
In [2]: x = np.random.normal(size=(500,1))

In [3]: y = np.random.normal(size=(500,))

In [4]: (x + y).shape
Out[4]: (500, 500)
```

This is a somewhat unintuitive application of [numpy's broadcasting rules](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html). Your result is actually going to be `869250 x 869250`, for a total of 5.5 terabytes of storage in the probably-default `np.float64`.

You more likely to want the vector sum. If you want to keep `x` as a `matrix` (which is often confusing, but...), you could do something like `x + y.reshape(-1, 1)`.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried checking how much memory each array needs?
well ... editing to include the comment here:

```
In [14]: b = np.random.random((2,3))

In [16]: b.itemsize*b.size
Out[16]: 48


In [17]: b = np.random.random((200,3))

In [18]: b.itemsize*b.size
Out[18]: 4800
```

now imagine that the results also needs a place to be saved ...

You didn't write what kind of data is in your numpy array, but if each item is 8 byte, then, already your first item (x) is  quite fat:

```
In [19]: 869250*8/1024 # the output is the size in KB ...
Out[19]: 6791
```

Comment: `sys.getsizeof` doesn't work with numpy arrays; `x.size * x.itemsize` would do that.